# GSON parsing with JSON giving NULL value

Tags: java, parsing, filter, gson

[image]

I want to access and print 'isOnlinePurchasable' but it's giving this error:

`error consuming topic: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.get(int)" because "conditionsObject.sellingControls" is null`

Here is my code:

```
public class conditions {
 public class JsonData{
        List<SellingControls> sellingControls;
    }
    
    public class SellingControls{
        ProductAttribute productAttribute;
    }

    
    public class ProductAttribute{
        private boolean isOnlinePurchasable;

        public boolean getisOnlinePurchasable(){
            return this.isOnlinePurchasable;
        }

        public void setisOnlinePurchasable(boolean isOnlinePurchasable){
            this.isOnlinePurchasable = isOnlinePurchasable;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my gsonParsing code:

```
    //converting string to obj;
    
    public gsonParsing(String message)
    {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
        JsonData conditionsObject = gson.fromJson(message, JsonData.class);
    
    }

}
```

I am stuck, I do not know how to print or get the boolean isOnlinePurchasable. Kindly help please!

Thanks!

Comment: I just need the isOnlinePurchasable and not the others. Is it possible not to map out everything and just a particular one with GSON? Thanks!

Comment: The problem might be that you have specified `FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE`, but in the screenshot showing the JSON data the member names are lowercased. Regarding only getting the value of one specific field, you could probably use [`JsonReader`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) for that, but you will have to manually keep track of the nesting level and check which name you have read and how to handle it.